# Converting very old version of Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a very large group of ai files that I want to convert to jpg, the problem is that the program that I'm using to convert doesn't recognize the ai files because they're old.

the files start with this:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 
%%Creator: Adobe Illustrator(R) 6.0
%%AI8_CreatorVersion: 8.0.1
%%For: (a) (@home)
%%Title: (a.ai)
%%CreationDate: (16-04-2000) (14:44)
```

So, is there a tool that converts them to a new version of illustrator, and then I use the program to convert them to jpg.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, Illustrator 6 from 1996. Illustrator CS6 is version 16, so that's the version 4 versions behind CS1.  Illustrator v8 and below used a file format based on post-script, so you can try broadening your searches to include v7, v8, v5 etc since it's likely that anything that supports one of these should support all, and you could try opening these files as postscript (.ps) files rather than illustrator.

Converting old Adobe files isn't easy, Adobe periodically phase out backwards compatibility. Postscript is near-universally supported, but illustrator-specific features  and markup around the post script aren't, so **results  may vary from file to file**. Some options:

(for all these options, if you can't convert to jpg in the program suggested, convert to eps, svg or pdf then open that in modern Illustrator and convert there. Again, results will vary from file to file)

- Try the free open source Illustrator rival **Inkscape**. [According to this thread](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13610&p=52928#p52909), In kscape can usually open old illustrator files as postscript files, and can open them with some illustrator-specific features preserved on some operating systems using  another open source package called [UniConvertor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/)
- You could try using [**UniConvertor**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/) on its own, or use [**SK1**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SK1_%28program%29), an open source vector design program by the same people that claims to open Illustrator 9 and older files - discontinued but the code should still work.
- You could try an **old version of illustrator**. There are trial versions that can be downloaded for some old versions from non-dodgy 3rd party sites, for example, here's [a link to CS3 trials](http://prodesigntools.com/download-adobe-cs4-and-cs3-free-trials-here.html). Might not work but it's worth a try. You might also be able to buy a second hand disk of Illustrator 6-8 on Ebay cheaply and legally (make sure you get the serial number with the disk).
- Find software from that era that was compatible with Illustrator files. **Freehand** should do the job. You can get a demo of the latest (2003) version from http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/freehand/ -  although you might need to dig out an old machine to run it. There may be older versions out there - Freehand has a lot of die-hard fans.

If you have a file that none of the above support, Wikipedia has a list of software that supports .ai files. The older the version you can find, the more likely it is to work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator_Artwork